# Can't select Blue Yeti Pro USB Microphone in sound settings menu

Tags: sound, 13.04, usb, pulseaudio, microphone

Today, I recieved a shiny new Blue Yeti Pro USB microphone in the mail. I did my research to make sure that it would work. I found the following websites, and this is what led me to believe that it would work without any issues, despite the fact that it is a USB 2.0 device:

http://community.linuxmint.com/hardware/view/12511

http://geardiary.com/2011/06/28/revi...hone-yeti-pro/

So- I got it out and plugged it in. The red light on the mute button lit up and started flashing, which means that the Mic is muted. I un-muted it- so far, so good. I went to the sound settings menu. It was recognized as: Digital Input (S/PDIF) BLUE USB Audio 2.0 and BLUE USB Audio 2.0 Analog Stereo. I tried to select them, one at a time as the input device. Each time I tried to select it, the sytem settings would crash and shut off.

Then, I tried to select it using JACK instead. In Jack, I was able to select it as the input device without issue. I fired up the JACK server and didn't get loads of xruns, so I opened Ardour. I couldn't get signal flowing in to Ardour no matter what I tried. Now It's getting frustrating. I shut off the JACK server and decided to try something else. So next I open a terminal and fire up

`alsamixer`

and got similar results, the microphone is recognized and I selected it as the sound capture device. The levels look good so I open Audacity and select the microphone as the capture device in Audacity. The same thing happened- no audio signal was getting in to the computer.

So, I decided to try installing and running

```
pavucontrol
```

. The microphone is recognized. Great. I can select it. Great. I fire up audacity again and the same thing happens- no audio signal to the computer. The next thing I tried was killing pulse and just using ALSA. I tried both`pactl exit`

and

```
pulseaduio --kill
```

and try selecting the microphone again with alsamixer- same result each time, no signal to the computer.

At this point, I'm really frustrated. I tried making sure of the the dumb stuff, like "is it plugged in" and "maybe I should try the other USB ports". No dice. I tried the direct headphone monitor on the mic to see if it's picking up sound at all, and it is. I'm completely baffled. when I run

```
lsusb
```

in a terminal I get the following output:

`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5710 IMC Networks 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 074d:0002 Micronas GmbH`

I uplugged it and ran

`lsusb`

one more time to see which device it was for sure. It's the Micronas GmbH device. At least that's some information. Then I ran`cat /proc/asound/cards`

and got the following output:

```
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xdfc00000 irq 52
1 [B20            ]: USB-Audio - BLUE USB Audio 2.0
                  BLUE BLUE USB Audio 2.0 at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2, high speed
```

Also, when I open the System Settings from the Terminal with gnome-control-center I get the following output with regard to audio:

```
(gnome-control-center:3593): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: active_output_update - couldn't find a stream from the supposed active output
(gnome-control-center:3593): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: active_input_update - couldn't find a stream from the supposed active input
```

When I try to select my microphone, the System Settings Window still closes and I get this in the terminal:

```
Segmentation fault
```

Maybe there's something useful there?

So- that's what I've got. A pretty sweet microphone that would be a really useful tool if it worked. I thought it would, and it doesn't. I am completely perplexed and don't know what I should do next. Does anyone have any ideas or advice?

Comment: Here's some more information. When I open the System Settings from the Terminal with gnome-control-center I get the following output with regard to audio:
(gnome-control-center:3593): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: active_output_update - couldn't find a stream from the supposed active output
(gnome-control-center:3593): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: active_input_update - couldn't find a stream from the supposed active input

When I try to select my microphone, the System Settings Window still closes and I get this in the terminal:
Code:

Segmentation fault

Maybe there's something useful there?

Comment: Also, the microphone appears to work fine with a 12.04.2 live DVD but not with a 13.04, Linux Mint 15 or Mint Debian edition live DVD- is there a way to roll back the driver to the previous version so I don't have to reinstall my whole OS??

Comment: I researched this issue extensively when using my Blue Yeti, and it turns out there is a bug in the driver.  I was hoping it would be fixed by now.  Try using `arecord /path/to/file.wav` from a terminal.  Speak into the mic while it's running.  Press `Ctrl+C` to stop it from recording.  Did anything happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since posting this question I have found a solution!

When Using JACK and Bitwig studio on 14.04, I was still getting the same behavior. It worked the first time, but was automatically muted for capture on subsequent reboots.  I am able to unmute the capture card using QasHctl now, where I was not able to do so in the Ubuntu Sound Settings Menu or Alsamixer.

That's it.  Just unmute the Yeti Pro Capture card in QasHctl.  Problem Solved!

Comment: Also, as time has passed since my last answer to this question, I should add that the device works perfectly well now- but only if I use it with pulseaudio enabled.

Comment: Can you give more info on how to set things up so JACK is used?